# angularfire send existing object to new list

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have a list in firebase, I've already set up master/detail routes, and then I get the list and individual objects to render on the components. however, I need to 'vet' each object and send to an 'approved' list.

I get an error — Error: Firebase.push failed: first argument  contains an invalid key ($ref) in property 'vetted.adlib'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

when I try to push or update the new list with this object. I guess is because it already has a push ID,

It doesn't have to work the way I'm doing now, I just want to be able to send an item in one list to another.

thank you in advance, I apologize if the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is because object, that you received from firebase contains `$key` and `$exists`.

To be able to push it to a new list you need to delete them manually or create an object in that won't parse those fields.

```
delete yourObject.$key;
delete yourObject.$exists;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that was my inclination.

Comment: Hey man, this is how im getting the object -- this.adlib = this.af.database.list('adlibs',{
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'id',
        equalTo: this.adlibId
      }
    }).map((items: Array<any>) => items.find(item => item.id === this.adlibId)) and this is how im trying to push it to a new list --   addToVetted() {
    const vet = this.adlib;
    
    delete vet.$key;
    delete vet.$exists;
    this.vetted.push(vet);

  }